# component is not render, problems with react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm having a problem with react-route. The `NoteList` component is not rendering.

app.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import logoNotes from './img/logoNotes.png';
import NoteList from './components/NoteList/NoteList';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className='aplication-notes'>
        <div className='notes-logo-container'>
          <img src={logoNotes} className='notes-logo' alt='logo' />
        </div>
        <div className='note-list'>
          <h1> my notes</h1>
          <br></br>
          <Routes
            path='/src/components/NoteList/NoteList'
            element={<NoteList />}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I can see the `div` and `h1` that is in the `app.js` file but not the `Notelist` component.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Routes` component is only responsible for wrapping `Route` components and handles the path matching duties. It doesn't take `path` or `element` props. These belong to the `Route` component.

Import the `Route` component and render the `NoteList` component by the `Route` and wrap the `Route` with `Routes`.

Example:

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes
  Route // <-- import
} from 'react-router-dom';
import logoNotes from './img/logoNotes.png';
import NoteList from './components/NoteList/NoteList';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className='aplication-notes'>
        <div className='notes-logo-container'>
          <img src={logoNotes} className='notes-logo' alt='logo' />
        </div>
        <div className='note-list'>
          <h1> my notes</h1>
          <br />
          <Routes> // <-- wrap Route components
            <Route // <-- Route renders content
              path="/src/components/NoteList/NoteList"
              element={<NoteList />}
            />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Now when you navigate to `"/src/components/NoteList/NoteList"` in the browser you should see the UI rendered as well as the `NoteList` component.